# Customization of a form widget in Symfony2/Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

In my form template:

```
{% block field_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    <label {{ block('widget_attributes') }}></label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

I need to add some extra `class` attributes and, of course, display the label (possibly translated). I've found that `{{ block('widget_attributes') }}` stores a `string` of attributes of the actual label.

Any chance to get an `array` type to easily modify it? Where i can find all `block` names to customize the appearance to fit my needs? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind Notepad++ helped me to find the file:

```
vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Resources\views
```

Three types of label defined:

```
{# Labels #}

{% block generic_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if required %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'class': attr.class|default('') ~ ' required'}) %}
    {% endif %}
    <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans }}</label>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}

{% block field_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
    {{ block('generic_label') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock field_label %}

{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    {{ block('generic_label') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```